# How do I make an array from a file containing numbers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, scope, project

Im fairly new to java, and I have a project to make a program that reads a file containing a list of numbers and calculates them. I want to make an array after reading the file, but can't seem to use the array 'scores[]' that I created in my makeArray method. Could someone please show me how to fix this error? I believe it is something to do with scope, I just can't figure it out. Also, I know lists can work instead of arrays but I can't use the for this project. Thanks!
P.S. sorry If my codes ugly

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class GradeFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = promptUser(console);
        for(int i = 0; i<= scores.length-1; i++) {
            double[] printArray = scores[i];
            System.out.print(printArray);
        }

    }


    public static Scanner promptUser(Scanner console) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner isThere = null;
        while(isThere == null) {
            System.out.print("Enter name of file: ");
            String fileName = console.next();
            try {
                isThere = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.print("File Not Found. ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("");
        return isThere;
    }


    public static double[] makeArray(Scanner input) {
        int length = 0;
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            double a = input.nextDouble();
            length++;
        }   
        double[] scores = new double[length-1];
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            for(int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
                double num = input.nextDouble();
                scores[i] = num;
        }


    }
    return scores;
}   

}
```

Comment: Well, what exactly is your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the makeArray method you've written. in the first loop you advance the scanner pointer to the end of the file.

surly if you try to read additional data there will be no more (next()).

the most simple solution is that you reconstruct your scanner passing it  the same file after completing the first loop.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question: where do I reconstruct this scanner? In the makeArray method or earlier in my program?

Comment: you should reconstruct it before you start the second loop. i would save the file path as a static variable and make a new Scanner(filepath) just before the loop starts

Answer (score 1):

you are going to the end of the file in an attempt to find the number of double values you need to store so that you can decide the length of the array. So when you are again using 
input.hasNext(); it returns null because you are already at the end of the file.

You can use an arrayList to read the numbers if you are unsure about how many you have to read. If you want you can cast it back to array

```
 public static double[] makeArray(Scanner input) {
    int length = 0;

    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while(input.hasNext()) {                           
            list.add(input.nextDouble());           
    }
    double[] scores = new double[list.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (double e : list)  
    scores[i++] = e;    

   return scores;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`makeArray` will always return an empty array.  After you scan through `input.hasNext()` you have consumed all of your input.  The second while loop will exit immediately because there is no more input.